# How to calculate start and end time in batch file calling from another batch file?

Tags: batch-file

Currently i am running mutiple batch files parallelling calling from master batch file. I want to calculate how much time it took to complete execution of all batch file.

e.g. I have MainScript.bat file which cals 20 more batch files simuteouslly. 
Now i want to know to how much time it took to complete the execution script.

Comment: Please provide more info: what you've tried, why didn't it work, etc..

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f %%x in ('wmic path win32_utctime get /format:list ^| findstr "="') do set %x
```

will set the variables `Day`, `DayofWeek`, `Hour`, `Minute`, `Month`, `Quarter`, `Second`, `WeekInMonth` and `Year` which you can use for your caclulation.

Comment: Want to calculte end time once child script completes execution

Comment: Yes, that means you take two snapshots of the then-current time and calculate.

Answer (score 0):

```
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:Timer ID
::
:: By:   Ritchie Lawrence, 2002-10-10. Version 1.0
::
:: Func: Returns number of seconds elapsed since the function was last
::       called and first called. For NT4/2K/XP.
::
:: Args: %1 (by ref) The first time this function is called, this variable
::       is initialised to '<last> <first> <init>' where <first> and <last>
::       are zero and <init> is the number of elapsed seconds since
::       1970-01-01 00:00:00. This value is used by subsequent calls to
::       determine the elapsed number of seconds since the last call
::       (<last>) and the first call (<first>).
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS&call set ID=%%%1%%
set t=2&if "%date%z" LSS "A" set t=1
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%a in ('echo/^|date') do (
  for /f "tokens=%t%-4 delims=.-/ " %%d in ('date/t') do (
    set %%a=%%d&set %%b=%%e&set %%c=%%f))
for /f "tokens=5-7 delims=:. " %%a in ('echo/^|time') do (
  set hh=%%a&set nn=%%b&set ss=%%c)
set /a dd=100%dd%%%100,mm=100%mm%%%100
set /a z=14-mm,z/=12,y=yy+4800-z,m=mm+12*z-3,j=153*m+2
set /a j=j/5+dd+y*365+y/4-y/100+y/400-2472633
set /a hh=100%hh%%%100,nn=100%nn%%%100,ss=100%ss%%%100
set /a j=j*86400+hh*3600+nn*60+ss
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims= " %%a in ('echo/%ID%') do (
  set l=%%a&set f=%%b&set c=%%c)
if {%c%}=={} endlocal&set %1=0 0 %j%&goto :EOF
set /a l=j-c-l,f+=l
endlocal&set %1=%l% %f% %c%&goto :EOF
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler timer tool:

Launch it like this:  timer.bat ping localhost

```
@echo off
set t1=%time%
call %*
set t2=%time%

call :showTime "Time taken:" "%t1%" "%t2%"
goto :EOF

:showTime
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%d in (%2) do set /a "t1=%%d*360000+1%%e*6000+1%%f*100+1%%g-610100"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%d in (%3) do set /a "t2=%%d*360000+1%%e*6000+1%%f*100+1%%g-610100, t=t2-t1"
echo.
echo %~1 %t%0 msec
pause
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Now it has call. :)  But you could have launched it like this too `timer call "second.bat"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to foxidrive for doing the work.  I needed a simple timer
I could call to show elapsed seconds.  Here is the modified code:

```
@echo off

set t1=%time%

:loop
call :print-elapsed-sec
PING -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
goto :loop

:print-elapsed-sec
setlocal
set t2=%time%
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%d in ("%t1%") do set /a "t1=%%d*360000+1%%e*6000+1%%f*100+1%%g-610100"
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=:." %%d in ("%t2%") do set /a "t2=%%d*360000+1%%e*6000+1%%f*100+1%%g-610100, t=t2-t1"
echo.
set /a "sec=t/100"
echo %~1%sec% sec
exit /b
```

Comment: Looks nice but this is not really a new answer, this is just another application of the same idea.